# How to translate a rectangle by its center in canvas?

Tags: canvas, center, translate

I'm pretty new to the canvas element, and I want to learn more because I think it has potential.  I have learned some openGL a few years ago (its a blur though), and I only remember few things.  With all that said, how would I be able to to translate an object, such as a rectangle, around its center or origin.  I know how you would rotate around its center; translating to the origin, rotate it, then translate it back.  Simple enough.  I tried that same concept for translating it around its center, but no avail.  The translation point is still at the top-left corner, and not in the center where I would like it to be.  Any tips on how I would do that?  I hope this isn't a dumb question, I'm just burnt out and can't program right today or something.

```
var width = 500;
var height = 400;
var x;
var y;
var rot;
var mx = 2;
var my = 2;

function init() {
    x = 0;
    y = 0;

    setInterval(draw, 1000 / 60);
}
function draw() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(x, y);
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, 30, 30);
    ctx.restore();

    document.getElementById("x").innerHTML = x;
    document.getElementById("y").innerHTML = y;
}

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    var event = e || window.event;

    /*if(x + mx > canvas.width - 15 || x + mx < 15) {
        x = (x + mx > canvas.width - 15) ? canvas.width - 15 : 15;
    }*/

    if(e.keyCode == 39) { // Right
        x = x + mx;
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == 37) { // Left
        x = x - mx;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to translate the corner of a rectangle to where its center is?

Comment: No, not that simple.  Im asking how or if it is possible to make the translation point the center of the rectangle.  The default is the top-left corner.  If I did ctx.translate(10, 10), it would move the rectangle 10 to the right and down according to the coordinates of the top-let corner; not the center.

Comment: How can you tell the difference?

Comment: Because if you mark the coordinates of where you are, they do not line up to the center of the rectangle?  Or when the center of the rectangle is on the edge of the canvas, it is either + or - half the width/height instead of 0.  Ex: If I have a rectangle that is 30 units long and wide, it will say either -15 or 15 as the coordinates, depending if you are going up or down and left and right (doesn't matter in this case since it is a square), instead of 0.

Comment: If I am doing bounds checking, I have to account for this offset which is annoying.  I want it to be symmetrical in my calculations.  Ex: I want the condition for checking the left bound on the canvas as width/2, not 0.  And the right bound should be the same, width/2.  But it isn't, and you have to adjust by doing canvas.width - width (of rectangle) to make sure the right edge of the rectangle hits the right canvas bound.  Understand?  didn't realize this was difficult to understand.. It is only a mere inconvenience that I was looking to fix.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are confused as to how translation transforms work. Rotation and scale transforms include multiplications, so the origin of the transform matters. For a rotation or scale, you translate to set the origin of the transform, perform the rotation or scale, and then translate back as needed.

Translations, though, are simply addition because every point that is transformed moves the same amount. There is no multiplication involved so the origin of the transform does not matter. If you want to move a rectangle 5 pixels to the left, you just create a transform that subtracts 5 from each X-coordinate.

For example, let's say you have a rectangle drawn on a canvas where the upper-left corner is at `(0, 0)` and the lower-right corner is at `(x, y)` (its center will be `(x/2, y/2)`). If you want to move the origin of the canvas such that the rectangle's upper-left is `(-x/2, -y/2)` and its lower-right is `(x/2, y/2)` (its center will be `(0, 0)`), you would translate the origin by `x/2, y/2`.

You haven't specified what language or environment you're using, but based on your example you would probably use something like:

```
ctx.transform(x/2, y/2)
```

Comment: This does not work.  All it does is divide the translation coordinates in half.  It does not move the point of translation which is the top-left corner.  That would be your (x, y), not (0, 0)

Comment: You should post a small sample of actual code that does not work, and show how its behavior differs from what you expect.

Comment: There, when you run a page with that the block will start at 0, 0 in the top left corner.  The pointer to the rectangle is also at the top-left corner.  The rectangle is being translated in relation to that top-left corner.  I would like to have it translate the rectangle by its center.  Your suggestion do not work either.  If just cuts the distance it moves in half.

Answer (score 0):

The general form to get a rectangle centered on a square canvas given you want the origin of the rectangle to be at the center of itself is:

`(totalCanvasWidth - rectXDimension)/2 = centerTransformPosition`

the same calculation applies to the y axis.